# How can I access a c# Memory Mapped File from Coldfusion 10?

Tags: c#, coldfusion, memory-mapped-files

I have a c# application that generates data every 1 second (stock tick data) which can be discarded after each itteration. 
I would like to pass this data to a Coldfusion (10) application and I have considered having the c# application writing the data to a file every second and then having the Coldfusion application reading that data, but this is most likely going to cause issues with the potential for both applications trying to read or write to the file at the same time ?

I was wondering if using Memory Mapped Files would be a better approach ? If so, how could I access the memory mapped file from Coldfusion ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have produced a number of stock applications that include tick by tick tracking of watchlists, charting etc. I think the idea of a file is probably not a great idea unless you are talking about a single stock with regular intervals. In my experience a change every "second" is probably way understating the case. Some stokes (AAPL or GOOG are good examples) have hundreds of "ticks" per second during peak times.

So if you are NOT taking every tick but really are "updating the file" every 1 second then your idea has some merit in that you could use a file watching gateway to fire events for you and "see" that the file is updated.

But keep in mind that you are in effect introducing something "in the middle". A file now stands between your Java or CF applications and the quote engine. That's going to introduce latency no matter what you choose to do (file handles getting and releasing etc).  And the locks of one process may interfere with the other.

When you are dealing with facebook updates miliseconds don't really matter much - in spite of all the teenage girls who probably disagree with me :) With stock quotes however, half of the task is shaving off miliseconds to get your processes as close to real time as possible.

Our choice is usually to choose sockets instead of something in the middle bridging the data. The quote engine then keeps it's watchlist and updates it's arrays like normal but also sends any updates down stream to the socket engine which pushes it to something taht can handle it (a chart application, watchlist, socketgateway for webpage etc).

Hope this helps - it's not a clear answer but more of a clarification to the hurdles you face.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response Mark, it's much appreciated. You are correct, I would be way understating the task if it was every tick I was after, I wouldn't even attempt that..my programming skills are quite limited. I am actually only after taking a read at 1 second intervals to give a somewhat "near" live overview. I am not terribly worried about adding a bit of extra latency but was worried about the locks you mention. That is why I thought a memory mapped file (non-persistent)  may be a better way ? but I have no idea how to access this file, once created, through CF :(

Comment: if you just want to get faster file i/o to make your idea work try using a virtual drive (software that creates a drive like "F:\" out of physical memory - transparent to other processes). That might get you there... good luck. You are going to pushing the limits of your approach :)